# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre SOAP y REST?

Tags: webservice, rest, soap

A la hora de hacer un `webservice` de momento siempre he escuchado esas dos opciones como claras candidatas, teniendo también en cuenta sus variantes.

Pero de momento por los artículos que he leído me sigue sin quedar muy claro.

La idea es poder evaluar, en qué casos puede ser más beneficioso usar una opción u otra, teniendo en cuenta beneficios y/o perjuicio que puedan tener.

Comment: Si tienes una duda sobre lo que **es** SOAP o REST, por favor más detalle de la cuestión que no tengas clara. Si la pregunta es "¿cuál es mejor?", se cerrará como basada en opiniones.

Comment: No estoy preguntando cual es el mejor... estoy preguntando por sus características y cómo funciona cada uno.

En ningún momento he propuesto en mi pregunta un debate.

Comment: http://www.chakray.com/que-diferencias-hay-entre-rest-y-soap/ Primer resultado de google

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SOAP y REST no pueden compararse directamente, ya que el primero es un protocolo (o al menos intenta ser) y el segundo es un estilo arquitectónico. Esta es probablemente una de las fuentes de confusión en torno a ella, ya que las personas tienden a llamar a cualquier API REST HTTP que no es SOAP.

SOAP se define como un protocolo estándar de comunicación (conjunto de reglas),  un intercambio de mensajes basado en la especificación de XML. SOAP utiliza diferentes protocolos de transporte, tales como HTTP y SMTP . El protocolo HTTP estándar hace que sea más fácil para el modelo de SOAP para túnel a través de cortafuegos y proxies sin ninguna modificación en el protocolo SOAP. SOAP a veces puede ser más lenta que las tecnologías de middleware como CORBA o ICE debido a su formato XML detallado.

REST describe un conjunto de principios de la arquitectura por el cual los datos se pueden transmitir a través de una interfaz estandarizada (como HTTP). REST no contiene una capa adicional de mensajería y se centra en las reglas de diseño para la creación de servicios sin estado. Un cliente puede acceder al recurso mediante el único URI se devuelve y una representación del recurso. Con cada nuevo recurso de la representación, se dice que el cliente para transferir estado. Si bien el acceso a los recursos REST con el protocolo HTTP, el URL del recurso sirve como el identificador de recursos y GET, PUT, DELETE, POST y HEAD son las operaciones HTTP estándar que se deben realizar en ese recurso.

Te dejo una imagen de una tabla para el entendimiento mas sencillo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mucho más claro con la imagen.