# Actualizar consulta SQL de una tabla en tiempo real en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, ajax

Como ven en este codigo estoy tratando de hacer una pagina web que filtre resultados de una base de datos.
Los resultados que da son el id, la cantidad y el dinero total de las ventas de la fecha que se selecciono.

```
        <form action="" method="post">
            <center>
            <p class="vt">Ventas por</p>
            <input type="text" name="enviar">
            <select name="select">
                <option value="value1" selected>Dia</option> 
                <option value="value2">Semana</option>
                <option value="value3">Mes</option>
            </select>

            <button type="submit" name="enviar">Filtrar</button>
            </center>

            <br>
            <center>
            <table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr> 
                <th>ID</th> 
                <th>CANTIDAD</th> 
                <th>INGRESO</th> 
                <th>FECHA</th>
            </tr> 

            <?php
                    require("con_db.php");

                    $sql = "SELECT v.id_venta, count(d.id_venta) as CANTIDAD, SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio) as suma, v.fecha AS f FROM ventas v INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta WHERE MONTH(fecha)=$mes; GROUP by f ORDER BY fecha ASC ";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conex,$sql);

                    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    ?> 
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['id_venta'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['CANTIDAD'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['suma'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $mostrar['f'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
            </table>
            </center>
        </form>
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma para que cuando presione el botón de filtrar la tabla cambie (Sin necesidad de recargar la pagina) al dia, mes o semana que se selecciono en el select y en valor de el input.
En pocas palabras lo que necesito hacer es que por ejemplo si el select tiene seleccionado Semana y el imput tene un valor de 5, al dar en el boton de filtrar, la tabla se recargue con el siguiente query

```
SELECT v.id_venta, count(d.id_venta) as CANTIDAD, SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio) as suma, v.fecha AS f FROM ventas v INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta WHERE WEEK(fecha)=5; GROUP by f ORDER BY fecha ASC
```

Cambiando el tipo a WEEK y el valor a 5.

Aqui esta la base de datos:
Tabla ventas:

```
CREATE TABLE `ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_usuario`, `fecha`) VALUES
(1, 2, '2020-04-25 06:33:56'),
(2, 2, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(3, 2, '2020-02-28 15:33:56'),
(4, 3, '2020-02-03 15:33:56'),
(5, 3, '2020-01-07 15:33:56'),
(6, 4, '2020-05-25 15:33:56'),
(7, 4, '2020-04-27 15:33:56'),
(8, 5, '2020-03-16 15:33:56'),
(9, 5, '2017-12-05 15:33:56'),
(10, 6, '2020-01-15 15:33:56'),
(11, 7, '2019-11-09 15:33:56'),
(12, 7, '2019-10-05 15:33:56'),
(13, 7, '2020-05-12 15:33:56'),
(14, 7, '2020-01-28 15:33:56'),
(15, 8, '2020-03-01 15:33:56'),
(16, 9, '2020-04-17 15:33:56'),
(17, 10, '2020-02-09 15:33:56'),
(18, 11, '2019-11-05 15:33:56'),
(19, 11, '2020-02-12 15:33:56'),
(20, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(21, 11, '2020-03-21 15:33:56'),
(22, 11, '2020-04-26 15:33:56'),
(23, 1, '2020-05-05 15:33:56'),
(24, 2, '2020-05-05 21:40:58');
```

Tabla detalle_ventas:

```
CREATE TABLE `detalle_ventas` (
  `id_venta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_producto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio` double NOT NULL,
  `cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `detalle_ventas` (`id_venta`, `id_producto`, `precio`, `cantidad`) VALUES
(1, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(1, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(1, 1, 40000, 2),
(2, 3, 25000, 1),
(3, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(4, 6, 12000, 1),
(4, 8, 7000, 2),
(4, 11, 5400, 1),
(5, 14, 560, 1),
(6, 10, 2300.56, 3),
(6, 13, 230, 2),
(6, 12, 300, 1),
(7, 16, 17000, 1),
(8, 4, 4898.99, 3),
(8, 1, 40000, 3),
(8, 9, 1000, 1),
(8, 10, 2300.56, 2),
(8, 15, 430, 2),
(9, 3, 25000, 1),
(10, 3, 25000, 4),
(11, 6, 12000, 2),
(12, 1, 40000, 1),
(13, 14, 560, 1),
(14, 4, 4898.99, 5),
(15, 7, 3000, 3),
(15, 9, 1000, 1),
(15, 13, 230, 1),
(15, 11, 5400, 1),
(15, 12, 300, 2),
(16, 13, 230, 1),
(17, 6, 12000, 1),
(17, 15, 430, 2),
(18, 8, 7000, 2),
(18, 7, 3000, 2),
(19, 2, 18000.9, 1),
(20, 4, 4898.99, 1),
(21, 12, 300, 2),
(21, 8, 7000, 1),
(22, 10, 2300.56, 1),
(22, 14, 560, 2),
(23, 5, 17, 5),
(23, 5, 17, 3),
(24, 2, 18000.9, 1);
```

Comment: Con ajax se puede lograr sin recargar la pagina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es utilizar ajax para realizar la peticion a tu archivo de php sin que se recargue tu pagina.

Ejemplo:

en html

```
<!--puedes agregar un id si requieres  enviar todo el formulario--->
<form id="form_filtro" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
    <center>
    <p class="vt">Ventas por</p>
    <input type="text" name="enviar">
    <select name="select">
        <option value="value1" selected>Dia</option> 
        <option value="value2">Semana</option>
        <option value="value3">Mes</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" name="enviar">Filtrar</button>
    </center>
</form>
<br>
<center>
    <table id="editable_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>ID</th> 
            <th>CANTIDAD</th> 
            <th>INGRESO</th> 
            <th>FECHA</th>
        </tr> 
        </thead>
        <tbody><!--contenido-->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</center>
```

en java script

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
$(document).on('submit', "#form_filtro", function (event, callback) {
    let filtrarPor=$("select[name='select']").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'consult.php',//ruta de tu archivo php en el cual se hace la consulta y se obtendra el resultado 
        type: 'POST',
        dataType:'html',//dataType: xml, json, script, o html
        data: {filtrarPor : filtrarPor },//se evia el valor seleccionado en tu select
        success: function (result) {       
            $("#editable_table tbody").html(result);//si la peticion se realizo sin errores te regresara un valor y lo insetas en tu table html
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status, error) {        
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

en tu archivo php

```
<?php
$filtro=$_POST["filtrarPor"];//es el dato que se selecciono en tu select
require("con_db.php");
//tu consulta lo adaptas dependiendo del valor de $filtro
$sql = "SELECT v.id_venta, count(d.id_venta) as CANTIDAD, SUM(d.cantidad * d.precio) as suma, v.fecha AS f FROM ventas v INNER JOIN detalle_ventas d ON d.id_venta = v.id_venta WHERE MONTH(fecha)=$mes; GROUP by f ORDER BY fecha ASC ";
$result = mysqli_query($conex,$sql);
$html="";
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $html.="
        <tr>
            <td>".$mostrar['id_venta']."</td>
            <td>".$mostrar['CANTIDAD']."</td>
            <td>".$mostrar['suma']."</td>
            <td>".$mostrar['f']."</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo $html;//utilizar utf8_decode($html) por si el contenido tiene caracteres especiales
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP es un lenguaje que corre en el servidor, es decir, cuando el usuario ve la pagina resultante en el browser el php ya termino de ejecutarse. PHP no puede hacerlo

Lo más sencillo es utilizar un servicio y AJAX. AJAX es un método para hacer consultas desde el front-end, es decir tu html, en "tiempo real". Así tu html puede contactar a otro archivo (un servicio) que hace la consulta que necesitas y te regresa la información.

¿Que necesitas?
1. Haz un web service con PHP que vaya a la base de datos y cargue e imprima la información que necesitas, debe tomar como parámetro el valor del select
2. En tu html haz un script que utilize AJAX para llamar ese servicio pasándole el valor del select
3. En el mismo script modifica los valores de tu html

Cuando elijas la forma de crear tu servicio te vas a encontrar con dos maneras de hacerlo, un servicio REST y un SOAP. Sin entrar en detalle: REST utiliza un JSON y SOAP XML.

Comment: Los formatos no dependen ni de soap ni de rest, de hecho en ambos casos tu software debe ser capaz de devolver en el formato solicitado

Comment: Hola, @BetaM. Es parcialmente correcto lo que dices. Esta respuesta de puede extender la información en cuanto a REST y SOAP https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76615/qu%c3%a9-diferencia-hay-entre-soap-y-rest